# BFS on a tree with lists

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search

So I'm building this tree which has 1..* Nodes where each node has a list which in themselves can have 1..* nodes.

The first three levels of the tree I can build just fine but then it won't work more if I don't code all the levels which are just plain stupid. The solution is of course to use some kind of recursive method and a BFS.

Basically, in my TreeBuilder class, I want to be able to call `tree.getNodesAtDepth(depth))` and get a list of all nodes that are at that depth. Problem is that I don't understand how I can implement the `getNodesAtDepth(depth)` method.

All the examples I find are for binary trees. An alternative is to have the addChild method take a depth argument so I can specify at which depth to insert the child at.

In the end, this is what I want:
I have a tree with a root. The root has a list which has 4 children nodes. I want to get the 4 children. For each child generate three nodes. So for child 0 has 3 children, child 1 has 3 children, child 3 has 3 children and child 4 has 3 children. And so forth

Maybe a possible soultion is to have a level attribute on each node and search for that node and then return it's parent. Beacuse it's parent should have a list of all the nodes at the searched for node.

Comment: Recursively iterate through the tree until you find the expected depth (actually `expected depth  -1 `), then collect all  children in that depth. You should recurse for all children. Use a temporary variable to increment the depth while you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
static void getNodesAtDepth(Node root, int currentLevel, int level, List<Node> nodes) {
    if(root == null) return;
    if(level == 0) {
        nodes.add(root);
        return;
    }

    if(currentLevel + 1 == level) {
        if(root.getNodeList() != null) {
            nodes.addAll(root.getNodeList());
        }
    }

    if(currentLevel < level) {
        if(root.getNodeList() != null) {
            for(Node node : root.getNodeList()) {
                getNodesAtDepth(node, currentLevel + 1,  level , nodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it :

```
List<Node> nodeList = new LinkedList<>();
getNodesAtDepth(root, 0, 2, nodeList);
```

`root` of course is the root of your tree. `nodeList` will store all your nodes at desired level (in my case it's 2). Second parameter is always `0`, (that's for keeping track of the current level)

Comment: what is zero +1?

Comment: @snackarMaker, ups, it's ``currentLevel`` , I've updated the answer

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! Thanks alot! Been ripping my hair of on this one! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I assume your class tree structure is :

```
class Tree {
    List<Tree> children
    ...
}
```

Then you can recursively iterate through the tree until you find the expected depth:

```
void recursivelyCollectNodesAtDepth(int depth,
                                    List<Tree> nodesAtDepth,
                                    Tree tree,
                                    int currentDepth) {

    if (tree == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (depth == 0) {
        nodesAtDepth.add(tree);
    } else if (currentDepth + 1 == depth) {
        // add children to the node list when expected depth is reached
        if (tree.getChildren() != null) {
            nodesAtDepth.addAll(tree.getChildren());
        }
    } else if (currentDepth < depth) {
        // iterate and recursively travers through child nodes
        for (Tree childTree : tree.getChildren()) {
            recursivelyCollectNodesAtDepth(depth,
                    nodesAtDepth,
                    childTree,
                    currentDepth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the tree nodes a recursively traversed to the expected level